# Management command does not show up when installed as third party

Tags: python, django

I am the author of [django-persistent-settings](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings). I have realized something odd.

The app has [various management commands](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/tree/development/persistent_settings/management). When I do `python setup.py --help` in django-persistent-settings project, the management commands do show up:

```
[persistent_settings]
    delvar
    getvar
    setvar
```

These commands are [also tested](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/tree/development/project/tests/test_commands) in the library. However, these commands do not show up when I install it to a project. I wonder why that is.

I have read [the related section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) but could not have found a warning, subsection or something alike regarding my problem. I have also checked the source code of some other projects having custom management commands such as [django-simple-history](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history) or [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework). They do more or less the same thing.

Is there maybe something I don't know? An issue I haven't seen but encountered somehow?

## Reanimating the Unexpected Behavior

Make sure Django 2 is installed and create a dummy project.

```sh
django-admin --version
# django 2.2.12 or something similar

django-admin createproject foo
cd foo
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install "django<3" django-persistent-settings
```

Open up `foo/settings.py` and add it `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "persistent_settings"
]
```

List commands:

```
python setup.py --help
```

And the commands do not show up.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.8
- Django 2.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add management package to `setup.py`. A dumb mistake.

Remember to add your management command subpackages to `packages` kwarg in `setup.py`.

```py
setup(
    # ...
    packages=(
            "persistent_settings",
            "persistent_settings.migrations",
            "persistent_settings.templatetags",
            "persistent_settings.management", # add this line
            "persistent_settings.management.commands", # and this line
        )
    # ...
)
```